# Best Practice - C# Windows Service managed by own PowerShell Module

Tags: c#, api, wcf, powershell

Can someone tell me some best practices to **interact with Powershell to a C# Windows service (own written).**
Which kind of interface should I implement (API).
All kind of **configuration** or changes should be **stored** somewhere.
Is there any recommendation about the logic I should use? (MSSQL, XML, ...)

**Example:** The Windows Service will receive requests over WCF. I want to implement RBAC to grant access using tokens (used in WCF). So the need is to create, set, get user/roles/permissions and there relations via the PowerShell Module.

Comment: Can you give us some use cases what you wan't to do?

Comment: Example: The Windows Service will receive requests over WCF. I want to implement RBAC to grant access using tokens (used in WCF). So the need is to create, set, get user/roles/permissions and there relations via the Powershell Module.

Comment: So you can connect to the WCF endpoint using PowerShell and invoke the methods using a generated proxy.

Comment: so i have to implement a "manage" WCF Endpoint that can be accessed by the PowerShell Module? How can I secure the Endpoint that only my Module can access it?

And my other question was: Where do I store all the information?

Answer (score 0):

Secure your endpoints using username / password credentials and use PowerShell to create WCF proxies which you can use to invoke the API.

I would store the information in a JSON settings file depeding on your needs (if they don't contain sensitive information)